# Is there an event I can subscribe to for when my Flutter route is active/on top or inactive/not on top?

Tags: flutter

In my Flutter app, I'd like to take various steps when my "page" is shown to the user, and other steps when my page is hidden from the user. For instance, subscribing to internal updates when my page is shown, and unsubscribing when the page is hidden.

I did find that I can tell in `build()` whether I'm currently on top with `ModalRoute.of(context)?.isCurrent ?? false` but that's not really what I'm looking for since that might not be called when my page reactivates.

One idea I had was that I might do something like this:

```
onPressed: () async {
  suspend();
  await Navigator.of(context).push(route);
  resume();
}
```

I could do that every time I navigate, but that seems like extra effort. Is that the best I can do, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an "easy" way to do this in flutter, built in through `RouteAware` and `NavigatorObserver`. Unfortunately, easy isn't always... easy.

To start, you need to add an observer to your MaterialApp. If you're using a state management system, you can use that to provide the RouteObserver, or you could just pass it as a global (which is what the flutter example does so I guess it's acceptable). If you're using a router instead of Navigator, you should still be able to add an observer to it and this *should* still function the same way.

That looks like this:

```dart
final RouteObserver<ModalRoute> routeObserver = RouteObserver<ModalRoute>();

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      navigatorObservers: [routeObserver],
      ...
    );
  }
}
```

Next, you need to make any widget you want to be aware of the route... `RouteAware`, which means two things. First, if it isn't already, it needs to become a StatefulWidget and you need to subscribe & unsubscribe to changes.

```dart
class MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> with RouteAware {
  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    routeObserver.subscribe(this, ModalRoute.of(context)!); 
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    routeObserver.unsubscribe(this);
    super.dispose();
  }

  ...
}
```

Finally, to actually respond to changes, you need to override the corresponding function in your State. Something like this:

```dart
class MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> with RouteAware {
  ...

  @override
  void didPush() {
    // page is currently active
    // I believe this gets called automatically after routeObserver.subscribe
    // page is active
  }

  @override
  void didPopNext() {
    // page is back to being active
  }

  @override
  void didPop() {
    // page is popped, will probably dispose next
    // probably want to unsubscribe in dispose
    // but could here as well
  }

  @override
  void didPushNext() {
    // now under another page, unsubscribe
  }
}
```

I tend to use a couple of abstract classes for convenience that make things quicker to write. Here's an example (see it on [dartpad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=0572c30616bdf3ff91cfcf3eb602d604)) using them to create a simple app that prints out whenever pages are popped and pushed:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final RouteObserver<ModalRoute> _routeObserver = RouteObserver<ModalRoute>();

abstract class RouteAwareState<T extends StatefulWidget, R extends Route<dynamic>> extends State<T> with RouteAware {
  final RouteObserver<R> routeObserver;
  bool _subscribed = false;

  RouteAwareState({required this.routeObserver});

  R routeRetriever(BuildContext context);

  @override
  @mustCallSuper
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    if (_subscribed) {
      routeObserver.unsubscribe(this);
    }
    routeObserver.subscribe(this, routeRetriever(context));
    _subscribed = true;
  }

  @override
  @mustCallSuper
  void dispose() {
    routeObserver.unsubscribe(this);
    super.dispose();
  }
}

// split this out so that you could implement observers for non-Modal routes
abstract class ModalRouteAwareState<T extends StatefulWidget> extends RouteAwareState<T, ModalRoute<dynamic>> {
  ModalRouteAwareState({required super.routeObserver});

  @override
  ModalRoute routeRetriever(BuildContext context) {
    return ModalRoute.of(context)!;
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(const IsCurrentRouteExample());
}

class IsCurrentRouteExample extends StatelessWidget {
  const IsCurrentRouteExample({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      navigatorObservers: [_routeObserver],
      routes: {
        "/": (context) => const PageN(0),
        "/1": (context) => const PageN(1),
        "/2": (context) => const PageN(2),
        "/3": (context) => const PageN(3, isLast: true),
      },
    );
  }
}

// for convenience, but specific to the routeObserver being a global variable
abstract class GlobalModalRouteAwareState<T extends StatefulWidget> extends ModalRouteAwareState<T> {
  GlobalModalRouteAwareState() : super(routeObserver: _routeObserver);
}

class PageN extends StatefulWidget {
  const PageN(this.n, {super.key, this.isLast = false});

  final int n;
  final bool isLast;
  bool get isFirst => n == 0;

  @override
  State<PageN> createState() => _PageNState();
}

class _PageNState extends ModalRouteAwareState<PageN> {
  _PageNState() : super(routeObserver: _routeObserver);

  @override
  void didPush() {
    print("${widget.n} Did push");
  }

  @override
  void didPopNext() {
    print("${widget.n} Did pop next");
  }

  @override
  void didPop() {
    print("${widget.n} Did pop");
  }

  @override
  void didPushNext() {
    print("${widget.n} Did push next");
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Center(
            child: Text("Page ${widget.n}"),
          ),
          if (!widget.isLast)
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () => Navigator.pushNamed(context, "/${widget.n + 1}"),
              child: const Text("Push"),
            ),
          if (!widget.isFirst)
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
              child: const Text("Pop"),
            ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```